# Fitting an ordinal response variable

Tags: regression, ordinal-data

Suppose $Y$ is an ordinal response variable with 4 levels (i.e. $Y$ can take on the values $1,2,3$ or $4$). We want to model $Y$ with $X_1, X_2$ using a proportional odds model. If $Y$ takes on the values of $1,2,3$ and $4$ an equal number of times (e.g. $Y = 1$ 4 times, $Y = 2$ 4 times, $Y = 3$ 4 times, and $Y=  4$ 4 times), will the estimates of some of the coefficients be 0?

Comment: Not necessarily - it depends on the values of $X_1, X_2$.

Comment: @Macro: Suppose $X_1$ and $X_2$ are binary and take on 1 and 0 an equal number of times.

Comment: Whether or not you will get 0 coefficients depends on how those outcomes correspond to the values of $Y$. If all possible combinations of $X_1,X_2$ occur equally often for each value of $Y$, then the coefficients for $X_1,X_2$ will be 0.

Comment: @Macro: How would you interpret the regression coefficients if they are 0? What if the y intercept is 0?

Comment: If you're fitting a 4-level ordinal response using a proportional odds model then there should be three "threshold" values that are returned, not just a single intercept (ordinal logistic regression is equivalent to a regression model of a logistic random variable that is thresholded to produce ordinal levels - the thresholds returned denote the changeover points on that latent scale). In a binary logistic regression model, a '0' intercept and '0' values for all coefficients tells me half of all samples a 0s and half are 1s, and that predictors are distributed exactly the same in both halves.

Comment: The coefficients from a proportional odds model are interpreted almost exactly the same as those from a logistic regression model, except that they measure a difference in log odds of being at least one category higher for a unit difference in the predictor. Of course, exponentiating the coefficient is recommended in practice.

Answer (score 3):

Macro's answered this pretty well in the comments but to illustrate, and in case there were any doubt remaining that the answer is "not necessarily, indeed it is unlikely":

```
> library(MASS)
> x1 <- sample(0:1, 1000, replace=T)
> x2 <- sample(0:1, 1000, replace=T)
> y <- ordered(sample(1:4, 1000, replace=T))
> polr(y~x1+x2)
Call:
polr(formula = y ~ x1 + x2)

Coefficients:
      x1       x2 
 0.16223 -0.05669 

Intercepts:
     1|2      2|3      3|4 
-1.04553  0.05007  1.19741 

Residual Deviance: 2769.64 
AIC: 2779.64 
> polr(y~x1*x2)
Call:
polr(formula = y ~ x1 * x2)

Coefficients:
     x1      x2   x1:x2 
 0.2466  0.0277 -0.1638 

Intercepts:
     1|2      2|3      3|4 
-1.00048  0.09521  1.24313 

Residual Deviance: 2769.12 
AIC: 2781.12
```